# Is Guest mode available in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, security, privacy

If a colleague at work wants my phone for an emergency call and I don't want him to take a peek at my call logs or SMS or photos. Is there a guest mode in Windows 10 Mobile for a scenario like this to protect my privacy? If it is there, how can I activate it?

My phone is Lumia 640 XL using Windows 10 Mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guest account in Windows mobile. But you can use Kids corner or apps corner in Windows mobile. This will give allow someone to use your phone but only the apps you allow.

Here is what Microsoft [says](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/share-apps-with-apps-corner) about Apps corner

> Apps Corner lets you set up a custom Start screen on your Windows
>   Phone 8.1, where you can share only the apps you choose with the
>   people you let use your phone.

Microsoft explains about kids corner in this [article](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/people/set-up-kids-corner) as follows,

> No such worries with Kid's Corner, a place on your phone where your
>   child can play with the games, apps, music, and videos you add there,
>   but can't get to the rest of your stuff.

You can find the difference about Apps corner and Kids corner in this [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/6139/18061) in Windowsphone SE site.

**References:**

1. [Apps Corner - windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/share-apps-with-apps-corner)
2. [Kids Corner - windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/people/set-up-kids-corner)
3. [Difference between apps corner and kids corner](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/6139/18061)
4. [How to setup and get out of apps corner - Nokia views](http://nokiaviews.com/how-to-set-up-and-get-out-of-apps-corner-in-windows-phone.html)
5. [How to set up apps corner in Windows 10 mobile - microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/set-up-apps-corner#v1h=tab01)

Comment: Thanks. I have chosen Apps corner and selected Phone app only, so my colleague makes his call. My problem still exists that he still can see all my call logs which I don't want to happen. Did you get my point?

Comment: @mms911 I get your point. Sadly you cannot hide your call history while sharing your phone app. Similar features are absent in Windows mobile. With apps corner you can atleast protect your messages, photos, whatsapp, etc... I suggest you make a feature request via Feedback app.